# Demo font bug and not showing character

Tags: css, next.js, fonts

I'm using the Core Sans font on my website, but when the "/" appears it doesn't show it, instead it shows this "demo" sign, how do I fix this problem?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mImY4.png)

I've tried changing the website from which I downloaded the font, but the problem persists.